# Mysql not run with my my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, my.cnf

i create a my.cnf file with mysqltuner but mysql not started with it,
and i get every time connection refused in my wordpress.
this is my my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]


#user                           = mysql
#default-storage-engine         = InnoDB

wait_timeout = 8
connect_timeout = 20
interactive_timeout=5
key-buffer-size=32M
myisam-recover=FORCE,BACKUP
thread_concurrency=8
max-allowed-packet=16M
max-connect-errors=1000000
datadir="/var/lib/mysql/"
# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size=512M
join_buffer_size =2G
max-heap-table-size=512M
query_cache_size = 512M
query-cache-type=ON
query_cache_limit=104857
max-connections=120
thread-cache-size=65
open-files-limit=65535
table-definition-cache=4096
table-open-cache=102400

log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group=2
#innodb-log-file-size = 16M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=1
innodb-file-per-table=1
innodb-buffer-pool-size=512G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

when i change my.cnf file to my old it work but problem steel not solved.
can anyone help me whats wrong in my.cnf file.

i solve problem by change my.cnf file to below code, thanks for your tips

```
[mysqld]


#user                           = mysql
#default-storage-engine         = InnoDB


key-buffer-size=32M
myisam-recover=FORCE,BACKUP
thread_concurrency=8
max-allowed-packet=16M
max-connect-errors=1000000
datadir="/var/lib/mysql/"
# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size=512M
max-heap-table-size=512M
query-cache-type=ON
query-cache-size=8MB
query_cache_limit=104857
max-connections=650
thread-cache-size=65
open-files-limit=65535
table-definition-cache=4096
table-open-cache=102400
# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group=2
#innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=1
innodb-file-per-table=1
innodb-buffer-pool-size=16G
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two configuration files?

Comment: Then quite obviously your new `my.cnf` has an error in it. Restore the old one, and then change one parameter at a time, restarting MYSQL after each change, until MySQL does not start again. Then you will know which parameter is causing you problems

Comment: @RiggsFolly i cant find the error

Comment: Do as I suggested. Start from a `my.cnf` that works. Change one parameter at a time until MYSQL does not start again. Then the last change you made is the parameter MYSQL does not like.

Comment: @Jens i upadate post

Comment: It is unlikely anybody will plough through the 2 files and try and look for an error. Do as I suggest.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i only post it for see it,

Comment: See this : https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/12893-system-variable-name-vs-option-file-format Maybe worth checking use of underscores & dashes in variable names and use the documented version (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html) -

Comment: You dont appear to be willing to put any effort into solving your own problems, even though I suggested a perfectly valid approach to a solution, so I for one feel equally unwilling to put any effort in either. Moving on to other things!

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks i solvet it and updated

Comment: Any clues as to how you solved it?

Comment: Do you really have _more_ than half a terabyte of RAM?  (`innodb-buffer-pool-size=512G`)

Comment: @Rick James Thanks for your response, yes its my mistake